# Custom html validation for select

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a select element like this:

```
<select name="select">
<option value="opt1">Select One Value Only</option>
<option value="opt2">Type 2</option>
<option value="opt3">Type 3</option>
</select>
```

and I want user to select a option e.g. opt2, opt3... but opt1,
how to to use html 5 validation to valid the select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to add the validation here is to set the default option value to an empty string and add [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) attribute to `select` element. Now you can click on submit button to see the validation:

```html
<form>
  <label >Choose an option:</label>
  <select name="select" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select One Value Only</option>
    <option value="opt2">Type 2</option>
    <option value="opt3">Type 3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The issue here is that when you set a value to the default option to something other than empty string the validation infers it as a valid value has been already selected, thus the validation is not triggered at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```html
<select name="select">
  <option value="opt1" selected disabled>Select One Value Only</option>
  <option value="opt2">Type 2</option>
  <option value="opt3">Type 3</option>
</select>
```

In the snippet above, the `opt1` is selected by default. The user can only select `opt2` or `opt3`, but once they do that then they cannot selecte `opt1`, hope this is the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, if a user does not select anything, the opt1 would be seleced, this is not expected.

Comment: I've updated my answer, removed the `value="opt1"` by accident.

Comment: How to remind the users to select opt2 or the other options if they forget to select a option in the selector?  Essentially, I want to use html5 validation to do this, but I do not know how to custom it.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using:

```
<select name="select" required>
  <option value="opt1" selected="selected" disabled>Select One Value Only</option>
  <option value="opt2">Type 2</option>
  <option value="opt3">Type 3</option>
</select>
```